# Obtaining exponential form of Bogoliubov Operator

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, second-quantization, unitarity

Dicke Model Hamilonian after Holstein- Primakoff Transformation in the large spin limit can be represented as -
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hat H = \omega \hat a^{\dagger}a + \varepsilon \hat b^{\dagger} \hat b + \gamma (\hat a^{\dagger} + a )(\hat b^{\dagger} +\hat b ) + e_o
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, my question is how to I diagonalize this hamiltonian using Bogoliubov Transformation?
I referred to [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.102.033702) paper. However, I am not sure how do they represent the transformation equations as an exponential

Any help or suggestions for further readings shall be appreciated.